# Why do smooth shapes minimise surface area?

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

When reading the [Wikipedia page on surface tension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension), I came across this statement:

> As a result of surface area minimization, a surface will assume the smoothest shape it can (mathematical proof that "smooth" shapes minimize surface area relies on use of the Euler–Lagrange equation). Since any curvature in the surface shape results in greater area, a higher energy will also result.

I am confused by the sentence inside parentheses. I thought that solutions to the Euler-Lagrange equation are required to be smooth; it has to be separately proved that the minimal solution is smooth (how?), before applying the Euler-Lagrange equation.

Comment: I have deleted (in the wiki page) the last sentence on curvature, which is just false. The other information are also extremely unclear, I suggest you find some book on CMC surfaces if you really want to understand the topics.

Comment: The question as worded is so mathematically vague that it is unanswerable.

Comment: For some constraints (think soap bubbles) solutions will be piecewise flat.

Comment: @DanAsimov I mean that since EL equations admit smooth solutions only, how are we able to "prove that solutions are smooth" using EL equations, as in the quote?

Comment: Which is shorter, a straight line between two points or a jagged line between two points? Now imagine a region of a surface. We decide to cover it. Is the surface area of a smooth cover the same as a wrinkled one?

Comment: This question neglects to state any clear mathematical hypotheses. That is why it is unanswerable.

Comment: The EL eqn in this case is a second order PDE, so an object doesn't have to be smooth  to satisfy the eqn (for example, $C^2$ is sufficient: of course there are more weaker conditions).

Comment: "Smooth" as the term is generally understood among mathematicians means infinitely differentiable. (As in the comment immediately above this one.) The word is sometimes used differently by others, so I am not clear about exactly what the original poster means by this word.